# Reading VM Option using ANT

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, virtual-machine

I am new to ANT Script. In my Java Project in Intellij, I set VM Option as "-Dapplication.system". How can I read this value using ANT? the goal is to read -Dapplication.system (it could be one of DEV,TEST,QS,PROD) Based on this value, corresponding config-*.properties file should be open and some new keys (credentials) will be added automatically. I am already hardcod the value of "-Dapplication.system" but I have no idea how to read it using ANT. I do folloeing line to test:

```
 <exec executable="java">
        <arg line="-Dapplication.system" if:true="${showextendedparams}"/>
```

but it seems that it does not do anything.

In the next step, by deploying on server (DEF,TEST,QS,PROD) the ant should be run automatically and add the ´credentials to the config-*.properties.

Thanks in advance Best regards